# Integrating Spring XML beans from external jar into a CDI application

Tags: spring, jar, javabeans, external, cdi

I have a new CDI Java EE application running on WebSphere. Now I want to use an existing module (.jar) in my CDI project, however the existing module uses Spring with Spring annotations and an Spring XML configuration file with additional bean definitions in it. Normally I would just import the Spring XML in my project, but in the CDI application this will not work.

I tried to load the Spring XML using JBoss Seam, like so:

@Produces
 @SpringContext
 @Configuration(locations = "classpath*:external-spring--context.xml")
 ApplicationContext context;

But the context is null? I cannot realy find good examples on how to do this, help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding an CDI producer that will create the Spring context using the spring XML file:

```
public class SpringBeansFactory {
    @Inject
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Produces
    public BusinesService getBusinessService() {
        return context.getBean(BusinesService.class);
    }
}

class SpringContextFactory {

    @Produces
    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
            return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-context.xml");
    }
}
```